# Regarding capturing and storing of user sessions on a Website

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video

I want to **record** and **Store video of user sessions** visiting on my website. So what should be the most effective way of recording user sessions ? Any suggestions for where to store them ?

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be *video*, the only way to do this is with a browser extension.  You can look at the tab capture API in Chrome.  There is a similar API available for Firefox.

It isn't possible to capture an entire tab in-page without an extension.

It *is* possible to capture a canvas however, and it is also possible to (very slowly) convert the current DOM into a static SVG and then draw that SVG to a canvas.  If you want about one frame every few seconds, along with terrible user performance, you could go that route too.

Comment: Thanks ! I would have a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

There are tools that allow you do this for tracking/debugging purposes. Some examples are https://www.hotjar.com, https://www.inspectlet.com/. A simple google search should give you a few options that you can evaluate and choose.

However you need to mindful in terms of how many user sessions you record. This is very n/w intensive.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! Above two are tools; I am making a tool myself & need to add a recording feature

Comment: Unless this is the main feature of the tool, I highly recommend not building this yourself. It will involve a lot of work to scale and be able to efficiently do this.

Comment: Yes , that's not the main feature . There would be other features to be followed